# Spring 5 :optional injection points using @Nullable

Tags: spring, nullable

**Spring 5** have added support Null-safety of Spring APIs. Now We can also use `@Nullable` to indicate optional injection points.

But i am not able to understand use case when we should use `@Nullable` dependency ?

spring documentation does not have examples about the `@Nullable` dependency

```
@Component
    public class SomeClass {

        @Nullable
        @Autowired
        private MyService service;  

        public void someMethod()
        {
            service.someMethod();       
        } 

    }
```

Comment: here is some information about it https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15540

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now We can also use @Nullable to indicate optional injection points.

I think that it makes sense if you dependency is not mandatory.
What you could write without `@Nullable` :

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private MyService service;
```

Now with this code :

```
@Nullable
@Autowired
private MyService service;
```

you could use a standard way to convey that the field may be `null`.
And according to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html), the standard way allows to take advantage of tools that support this annotation :

> Leverages JSR 305 meta-annotations to indicate nullability in Java to
>   common tools with JSR 305 support and used by Kotlin to infer
>   nullability of Spring API.

Note that `@Nullable` on a dependency is a case among others.
On the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html), you can also read :

> A common Spring annotation to declare that annotated elements can be
>   null under some circumstance.

and also :

> Should be used at parameter, return value, and field level. Methods
>   override should repeat parent @Nullable annotations unless they behave
>   differently.

So, it makes sense also to decorate method return :

```
@Nullable
public Foo doThat() {
   ...
}
```

or parameters :

```
public Foo doThat(@Nullable Bar) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for detail explanation. Could you please share some scenario  where we might need required = false. I think it can be consider as code smells and we should refactor the the class

Comment: You are welcome. Beyond the Spring `@Nullable` adding, generally it is indeed a bad idea to have `null` things : fields, parameters, etc...
Now in some very specific cases, you could have a `null` field. Suppose your application relies on a third party JAR to discover and load in the Spring container a specific bean.  Suppose that in some circumstances the bean implementation cannot be resolved. By using `required=false`  for your field and a fallback strategy located in a PostConstruct hook for example, you can recover this issue.